# require() not working for node-webkit 6.0

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I am just trying to get started with node-webkit however when I try to use `require()` I get the error `[60904:0624/190000:INFO:CONSOLE(92)] "Uncaught AssertionError: missing path", source: assert.js (92)`. I am starting up node-webkit with the following command `./node-webkit.app/Contents/MacOS/node-webkit .` My package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name" : "nw-subset",
  "main" : "Subset.html",
  "window" : {
    "toolbar" : true,
    "frame"   : true
  }
}
```

I have tried just running `require('os')` and `window.require('os')` and both give me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error. For me, the issue was that I also had [ace.js](http://ace.c9.io/) loaded, which also assigns a global `require` function.

To solve this, you can add the following code snippet: ([source](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/faq-name-conflict))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.requireNode = window.require;
    window.require = undefined; 
</script>
```

in the `head` of your main html file. Then just use `requireNode` instead of `require`.